# What's the equivalence of typings globalDevDependencies for npm @types packages?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, npm, typescript-typings

I want to upgrade an tsc@1.8 project to tsc@2 and in the process ditch `typings` from my tool chain.

It's not a problem for the common depencies as these dependencies from my `typings.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bluebird": "registry:npm/bluebird#3.3.4+20160515010139",
  "lodash": "registry:npm/lodash#4.0.0+20160416211519",
  "mime": "registry:npm/mime#1.3.0+20160423043021"
}
```

I can easily install via

```
npm i @types/bluebird @types/lodass @types/mime
```

Yet I also have some `globalDevDependencies` for my test setup in my `typings.json`:

```
"globalDevDependencies": {
  "mocha": "registry:dt/mocha#2.2.5+20160317120654"
}
```

My first try was:

```
npm install @types/mocha --save-dev
```

Yet now `tsc` complains it doesn't know the `mocha` functions `it` and `describe`.

```
tests/unit/HelloServiceTest.ts(4,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
tests/unit/HelloServiceTest.ts(5,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
tests/unit/HelloServiceTest.ts(10,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
```

As a longshot I mistakenly thought installing those globally might resolve the issue:

```
npm i @types/mocha  -g
```

I also stumbled across [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1054) where the solution was to not exclude the types folder in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "!node_modules/@types"
]
```

yet it also didn't work for me, throwing the same error.

In the end, I don't know how to achieve the same effect that `typings`' `globalDevDependencies` and `globalDependencies` had when I want to use just `npm` and the `@types/*` packages instead of `typings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/36722028-compilation-error-with-mocha-and-typescript-2-0-on-windows-10) pointed me in the right direction, as I have to add the types to the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "types": ["node", "mocha", "chai"],
    ...
}
```

[The types option also have a verbose documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. My interpretation of the documentation is that these typings should be included by default though so it's a bit confusing that it doesn't work without this. "By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation."