# Mocha typings broken for TypeScript 2.4.1?

Tags: typescript, webpack, mocha.js, definitelytyped

After upgrading my Typescript version from 2.3.x to 2.4.1 I'm running into the following error:

```
ERROR in *path*/tsconfig.json
    error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'mocha'.
```

Is my project configuration wrong or do these typings need to be updated somehow? The typings are definitely still there, they must just be referenced differently by TypeScript 2.4?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "rimraf dist && npm run build:client && npm run build:server",
    ...
    "build:client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.client.config.js --progress --hide-modules",
    "build:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.server.config.js --progress --hide-modules",
    ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=7.0",
    "npm": ">=4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/express": "4.0.36",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.48",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.41",
    "@types/node": "7.0.32",
    ...
    "chai": "4.1.0",
    ...
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    ...
    "vue-ts-loader": "0.0.3",
    "webpack": "3.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.6.0",
    "webpack-shell-plugin": "0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "out/",
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16772)

Comment: Long shot: Try setting the types in tsconfig. I use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885903/457268) for mocha, yet it might also be enough to set an empty array.

Comment: I recommend you to try typings and use typeRoots": ["/typings/"]. The types in npm are outdated.

Comment: Thanks @k0pernikus. I'm not using ts-loader (which appears to have been fixed), but perhaps vue-ts-loader has the same issue. I'll investigate that.

Comment: The following question pointed me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885537/whats-the-equivalence-of-typings-globaldevdependencies-for-npm-types-packages/40885903#40885903

Answer (score 0):

The following question helped me solve the issue:

[What's the equivalence of typings globalDevDependencies for npm @types packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885537/whats-the-equivalence-of-typings-globaldevdependencies-for-npm-types-packages/40885903#40885903)

This seems like an unnecessary workaround from my understanding of the documentation at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

However, it got me up and running again.